# Report table where each column is derived by a separate independent query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-server-2012

I have multiple SQL queries that each generate an aggregate column output i.e. One sql query returns a Max of a column, another returns a sum of all values in a column, and so on. I want to display all these values as a single record in a table. For Example.

```
Total_Employees    Total_Employees_In_US    Bonus_OF_Employees_Under_25
```

This is just an example. All columns are independent of each other but need to be displayed in this way. I tried to google my question but I am unable to phrase it correctly to get any clues. I am sure this problem must have been answered but I am just not able to reach it. Is there any link where this problem has been solved ? Any pointers to a correct path is helpful. I shall delete this question if it has been answered already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use separate queries if you want:

```
select
    (select count(*) from employees) Total_Employees,
    (select count(*) from employees where country = 'USA') Total_Employees_In_US,
    (select sum(bonus) from employees where age < 25) Bonus_OF_Employees_Under_25
from dual
```

Or in this example, just one relatively simple query:

```
select
    count(*) Total_Employees,
    sum(case when country = 'USA' then 1 end) Total_Employees_In_US,
    sum(case when age < 25 then bonus end) Bonus_OF_Employees_Under_25
from employees
```

---

To produce groups:

```
select
    EmployeeCategory,
    count(*) Total_Employees,
    sum(case when country = 'USA' then 1 end) Total_Employees_In_US,
    sum(case when age < 25 then bonus end) Bonus_OF_Employees_Under_25
from employees
group by EmployeeCategory
```

Comment: I have an extra column called EmployeeCategory and all other columns need to be 'Group By' on this. Is it possible to tweak the solution to resolve this?

Comment: @Xion yes you can do it - it's a straightforward group-by, but it's only possible with the second version of the query. See addendum to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your individual queries can be in the `CTE` and you can do final join.
This is just an example, in this case, single GROUP BY should have worked, as i don't know your queries, you can do similar thing.

```
; with cte as
(
select COUNT(*) as Total_Employees, Record# from TableA
GROUP BY Record#
), 
cte1 as
(
select COUNT(*) as Total_Employees_In_US, Record# from TableA
where  -- some condition
group by Record#
)
select cte.Record#, cte.Total_Employees, cte1.Total_Employees_In_US
from cte
join cte1
on cte1.Record#= cte.Record#
```

Comment: I am able to do it with Record#. Can it be done without Record# ? I am editing my question to remove that column as all records are independent of each other.

Comment: yes it is , ; with cte as
(
select COUNT(*) as Total_Employees from TableA

), 
cte1 as
(
select COUNT(*) as Total_Employees_In_US from TableA

)
select cte.Total_Employees, cte1.Total_Employees_In_US
from cte, cte1